# Change Image Background Colour When Image Upload via PHP

Tags: php, image

I have simple PHP code for Upload Image On the server.

index.php

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
    </form>
```

upload.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{ 

    $move = "/var/www/html/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $sidd = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $siddName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($sidd, $move)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

}
```

Any Idea:- How I can set image-background "white" and then upload on server ????? so image will show with white background on website and also store with white background.

Note:- I do not want to use any third party paid API.

Comment: You could just have a html elemental wrapping the image when displayed and set that to a white background. Or lookup php image manipulation library in a search there are a ton of open source ones that can do that.

Comment: @Danny Thanks for support. Can you give me any example. ?